# How to interpolate an object's key name in JavaScript/JSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this line of js:

```
overlay.animate({"left":"-1000px"}, "slow").removeClass('visible');
```

I need to use a variable (direction) instead of the word "left", how can I rewrite this string?

This doesn't work:

```
overlay.animate({direction:"-1000px"}, "slow").removeClass('visible');
```

thanks

Comment: have you considered using D3 http://d3js.org/

Comment: What is the problem you are face to assigning variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `[]` to access keys with a variable.

```
var options = {};
options[direction] = "-1000px";
overlay.animate(options, "slow").removeClass('visible');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var json = {};
json[direction]=theDirection;
overlay.animate(json, "slow").removeClass('visible');
```

This should works.